# How can I use 'initial begin in the uvm?

Tags: uvm

I'm trying to implement some systemverilog code within the  UVM code.

but I come across one syntax error when I comple the uvm code as the below.

```
@test.sv
    initial begin
        #100 $finish;
    end
```

***Error-[se] Syntax error***

> Following verilog sourve has syntax error :
>
> "test.sv", 70 :  token is 'inital"
>
> inital begin

Can't use initial begin syntex at the uvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your test.sv file is a class, initial blocks are not permitted in classes for SystemVerilog. This isn't a UVM restriction, but a SystemVerilog one.